# Is there a way in Jenkins to create a manual approval for a job to be approved by multiple approvers?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a promotion Job A which on successful build triggers email to certain recipients with Jenkins console link and build#. When the user clicks on the link from the email, he will login through his user id and clicks on approve, upon which Job B in the pipeline triggers. Now I want to achieve this for multiple approvers, meaning if Job A sent email to 3 users, Job B should not be triggered until all approvers approve. Seems like their is no option in promoted build plugin for the same. Any ideas, suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

May be this plugin can help you with the approvals.

[Build Pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin)

This plugin provides a Build Pipeline View of upstream and downstream connected jobs that typically form a build pipeline.  In addition, it offers the ability to define manual triggers for jobs that require intervention prior to execution, e.g. an approval process outside of Jenkins